# proper redirect with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is there a way to redirect a client, with .htaccess based on an IP in such a way that if they log their path, instead of seeing your site they only see the one that they are redirected to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this inside your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://othersite.com [R=301,L]
```

If they're using any sort of tool that can detect packets, or header information, they'll see what's going on behind the scenes; however, they won't ever notice it in their browser experience.

Comment: So, if they come on any page can I do something like: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:///othersite.com [R=301,L]? Also if I know part of their address, DNS I suppose, instead of IP, like ...snooper.net

Comment: I can't say 100% for sure if you're greedy match will work for all cases, but that's the basic idea. If you only want to match the first few octets of a IP, you can just do this `^123\.123\.`